# How to increase number of Xv adaptor ports?

Tags: x-server, xorg.conf, gstreamer

The number of xv video ports is to low for my use cases e. g. xvinfo reports:

```
X-Video Extension version 2.2
screen #0
  Adaptor #0: "GLAMOR Textured Video"
    number of ports: 16
    port base: 164
```

How to increase the number to 32 or better 64 ?

Also gstreamer can not create more than 16 xvimagesinks, because no more ports are avaliable.